# How do I use filter inside filter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array getting from an API data, I would like to filter categories if it's in category. I was trying like **:**

```
data.filter((post) => post.categories.filter((category) => if(category._id === category) return category
```

It didn't work for me

Here is my array data **:**

```
export interface Post {
  categories: Category[]
  publishedAt: string
  _id: string
  _createdAt: string
  title: string
  author: {
    name: string
    image: string
  }
  comments: Comment[]
  description: string
  mainImage: {
    asset: {
      url: string
    }
  }
  slug: {
    current: string
  }
  body: [object]
}

export interface Category {
  _id: string
  _ref?: string
  title: string
}
```

and I tried this too

```
posts.map((post) => {
  post.categories.filter((category) => {
    if (category._ref === isCategory) return category;
  });
  {
    return <Posts post={post} />;
  }
});
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: do you want to filter the posts having the specific category in its categories list?

Comment: Why don't use use just one filter and use includes() method on post.categories to see it it includes the category you are searching for ? I m guessing you are trying to filter posts by categories.

Comment: @Rihabsabri you're right , but contains will not work since post.categories it's array of object it's not array of string so he need to use findIndex or some ^^

Comment: Yes I wanted to filter the posts by categories I solved my problem thanks for all of answers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at first get the list of post that have in the array category the dedicated category.
Try this solution

```js
const postsWithCategory = posts.filter((post) => post.categories.findIndex(cat => cat._ref === isCategory) !== -1);
postsWithCategory.map(post => (<Posts post={post} />));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get the posts having a specific `category`. You can filter the posts based on if some of the categories are equal to the defined `category` id.

Try like this.

```
{data
  .filter((post) => post.categories.some((cat) => cat._id === category))
  .map((post) => (
    <Posts post={post} />
  ))}
```